# How to draw a charts by flash cs5

Tags: game-design, flash, actionscript-3, analytics

Hey all , I want to make something more interesting in my game some thing like a **charts Analysis** for a flash game. **When THE PLAYER FINISH THE GAME**  . The score appears in charts . I want to integrate it with ***actionscript3*** .

**NOTE**

The game is 60 seconds only I want to draw the score of the user in Y-axis And the Time in X-axis .

I read before about [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/), but i didn't get much information if there are something easier I'll be grateful .
something like that

[image]

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: The title "How to make a score charts analysis" or any methods to do it .

Comment: or any flash plugins help to do it .

Comment: why not just create your own chart? They are not that hard to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo also has a As3 Charting-library available: http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/charts/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are asking about how to get the data or how to draw the chart. In the second case you might want to have a look at Google Charts drawing service: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html

Comment: I mean the second case .